# Did Voldemort choose to kill Harry on Halloween intentionally?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Did he intentionally choose Halloween as a significant date that "worked" with what he was about to do, or just that happened to be the day that he was able to go to Godric's Hollow, or the day when Wormtail told him the secret hiding place?

Comment: He knew passers by wouldn't make comments about his nose.

Comment: I doubt Voldemort gave a crap about what Muggle's thought of his appearance. I think it was just a coincidence that Wormtail informed him on that day. He would have wanted to finish the job as quickly as possible, and surprise the Potters, while Wormtail's betrayal was still unknown to them.

Comment: He was actually just out trick-or-treating. He went to the Potter's house and was dressed up as Death. Lily blew his costume out of proportion and tried to attack him, poor Voldey was forced to defend himself. The story of Harry Potter is actually about Voldemort trying to get revenge for his mom not giving him candy that evening whilst trick-or-treating.

Comment: Have we found out if Halloween is a big deal in magic world? It is in the muggle world though all we see is feasting so far. Though i am not active on Pottermore

Answer (score 7):

### Maybe, but perhaps not for the obvious reason

Wormtail seemed depressed when he last saw Lily:

> Wormy was here last weekend. I thought he seemed down, but that was
>   probably the news about the McKinnons; I cried all evening when I
>   heard.

Harry speculates that Wormtail had already betrayed the Potters:

> *Wormy was here* . . . Pettigrew, the traitor, had seemed “down” had he? Was he aware that he was seeing James and Lily alive for the last
>   time?

We know that Dumbledore had James's invisibility cloak:

> James is getting a bit frustrated shut up here, he tries not to show
>   it but I can tell—also Dumbledore’s still got his Invisibility Cloak,
>   so no chance of little excursions.

We also know that he had been shown the cloak several days before Harry's parents died.

> "You have guessed, I know, why the Cloak was in my possession on the
>   night your parents died. James had showed it to me just a few days
>   previously."

From this, we know that "last weekend" in the first quote must refer to the weekend before Harry's parents were killed. Halloween 1981 was on a Saturday. Suppose Harry was right that the reason for Wormtail's low spirits was that he had just broken Lily and James's trust in him.

**Perhaps Wormtail betrayed the Potters a week before Voldemort killed them.**

But why?

Well, to my knowledge there was no evidence that Voldemort was obsessed with Halloween. But he certainly *was* obsessed with the number seven. It would be perfectly in character for Voldemort to destroy the biggest threat to his life precisely ***seven  days after gaining the means to do so***.

**Halloween is also a big Wizarding holiday.**

There is a Halloween feast every year at Hogwarts, so it is not merely a Muggle holiday.

Comment: The last point is probably the strongest. A holiday is a holiday. People lower their guard, less Aurors on active duty, etc.

Comment: This is all good speculation (and +1 for it), but by no means certain. My own interpretation has always been that Wormtail was down because he was debating with himself whether to give up his oldest friend to Voldemort or not—and a week after his last visit to their house, he decided to do it. I don't think Voldemort would risk an entire week passing after the breaking of the Fidelius Charm before going there for the intended kill—too many unknown risk factors. He'd want to do it immediately, so there was no time for the Potters to be alerted to the fact that the spell was broken.

Answer (score 1):

I'll happily admit that this is mostly speculation but, on the balance of probabilities, I would answer no. Voldemort's perspective of the evening takes note of the costumes of Muggles that night.

> *The night wet and windy, two children dressed as pumpkins waddling across the square, and the shop windows covered in paper spiders, all the tawdy Muggle trappings of a world in which they did not believe...and he was gliding along, that sense of purpose and power and rightness in his that he always knew on these occasions...*
>
> *"Nice costume, Mister!"*
>
> *He saw the small boy's smile falter as he ran near enough to see beneath the hood of the cloak, saw the fear cloud his painted face: then the child turned and ran away...beneath the robe he fingered the handle of his wand...one simple movement and the child would never reach his mother...but unnecessary, quite unnecessary...*
>
> *(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17, Bathilda's Secret)*

I've always read the description of Halloween here as being deeply ironic. Just as the child is surprised that the 'costume' that Voldemort's wearing is not just make-believe, Voldemort too is surprised by the presence of all the Muggle paraphernalia. Almost as if he set out and then noticed once he got near a Muggle hospot that they happened to be celebrating Halloween.

If you think about it, it must have been a pretty infuriating sight for Voldemort. His whole ideology is based on wizarding supremacy and so to see Muggles dressed up as wizards and witches as part of a party or festival would've seemed like taunting to him. Imagine that you're Santa Clause and you weren't aware of all the movies/toys/stories that had built up around you. You go out for a quiet drink and then see everyone dressed up as you and think, "Oh, yeah, it's Christmas, isn't it? I'd forgotten." Except instead of dressing up as a friendly gift-giver these Muggles are unwittingly impersonating the most fearsome dark wizard of all time. To his face.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it really mattered to him, the date. it may have just seemed funny to him. it might have just been coincidence. but Voldemort does not seem to be the type of person to choose a certain date to kill his enemy. he is a man of action.

Comment: Well, he does have that weird obsession with choosing historically significant objects to house pieces of his soul, and even waiting to make his last Horcrux using a significant murder (that of Harry). Neither of these things seem to be motivated by any practical concerns.

Comment: Had to downvote this, because (as @sumelic hints at), Voldemort is **exactly** the type of person to choose certain, symbol-laden date to kill his primary enemy. Symbolism permeates nearly everything he does throughout the series.